# String.charAt() String Index out of bounds exception

Tags: java, arrays, string, exception

I have this program that creates a 'Stadium' full of seat objects that each have a section number, row number and a byte associated with it. The class has three String arrays that have those details associated with it in the format I would like the seats to be arranged in. A for loop then takes the characters inside each of the strings, creates the seat objects and adds it to a two dimensional Seat array with the same layout.

```
public class Stadium { 
    public static int ROWS = 27; 
    public static int COLUMNS = 35; 

    private static String[] SEAT_NUMBERS = { 
        "9 1234567890 123456789 1234567890 1", 
        "8 1234567890 123456789 1234567890 2", 
        "7 1234567890 123456789 1234567890 3", 
        "6                                 4", 
        "55   12345678 1234567 12345678   15", 
        "44 8  1234567 1234567 1234567  1 26", 
        "33 77                         12 37", 
        "22 66   1234561234567123456   23 48", 
        "11 55 0  12345123456712345  1 34 59", 
        "99 44 98  123412345671234  12 45 11", 
        "88 33 876 --------------- 123 56 22", 
        "77 22 765|               |234 67 33", 
        "66 11 654|               |345 78 44", 
        "55       |               |       55", 
        "44 87 543|               |456 11 66", 
        "33 76 432|               |567 22 77", 
        "22 65 321 --------------- 678 33 88", 
        "11 54 21  432176543214321  89 44 99", 
        "95 43 1  54321765432154321  0 55 11", 
        "84 32   6543217654321654321   66 22", 
        "73 21                         77 33", 
        "62 1  7654321 7654321 7654321 8  44", 
        "51   87654321 7654321 87654321   55", 
        "4                                 6", 
        "3 0987654321 987654321 0987654321 7", 
        "2 0987654321 987654321 0987654321 8", 
        "1 0987654321 987654321 0987654321 9" 
         }; 

   private static String[] SEAT_ROWS = { 
         "Z CCCCCCCCCC FFFFFFFFF IIIIIIIIII K", 
         "Z BBBBBBBBBB EEEEEEEEE HHHHHHHHHH K", 
         "Z AAAAAAAAAA DDDDDDDDD GGGGGGGGGG K", 
         "Z                                 K", 
         "ZY   BBBBBBBB DDDDDDD FFFFFFFF   JK", 
         "ZY T  AAAAAAA CCCCCCC EEEEEEE  H JK", 
         "ZY TS                         GH JK", 
         "ZY TS   CCCCCCFFFFFFFIIIIII   GH JK", 
         "ZY TS X  BBBBBEEEEEEEHHHHH  L GH JK", 
         "DC TS XW  AAAADDDDDDDGGGG  KL GH AB", 
         "DC TS XWV --------------- JKL GH AB", 
         "DC TS XWV|               |JKL GH AB", 
         "DC TS XWV|               |JKL GH AB", 
         "DC       |               |       AB", 
         "DC RQ XWV|               |JKL IJ AB", 
         "DC RQ XWV|               |JKL IJ AB", 
         "DC RQ XWV --------------- JKL IJ AB", 
         "DC RQ XW  SSSSPPPPPPPMMMM  KL IJ AB", 
         "XW RQ X  TTTTTQQQQQQQNNNNN  L IJ LM", 
         "XW RQ   UUUUUURRRRRRROOOOOO   IJ LM", 
         "XW RQ                         IJ LM", 
         "XW R  OOOOOOO MMMMMMM KKKKKKK  J LM", 
         "XW   PPPPPPPP NNNNNNN LLLLLLLL   LM", 
         "X                                 M", 
         "X TTTTTTTTTT QQQQQQQQQ NNNNNNNNNN M", 
         "X UUUUUUUUUU RRRRRRRRR OOOOOOOOOO M", 
         "X VVVVVVVVVV SSSSSSSSS PPPPPPPPPP M" 
         };                                    

    private static String[] SEAT_SECTIONS = {      
         "3 3333333333 333333333 3333333333 3", 
         "3 3333333333 333333333 3333333333 3", 
         "3 3333333333 333333333 3333333333 3", 
         "3                                 3", 
         "33   22222222 2222222 22222222   33", 
         "33 2  2222222 2222222 2222222  2 33", 
         "33 22                         22 33", 
         "33 22   1111111111111111111   22 33", 
         "33 22 1  11111111111111111  1 22 33", 
         "44 22 11  111111111111111  11 22 44", 
         "44 22 111 --------------- 111 22 44", 
         "44 22 111|               |111 22 44", 
         "44 22 111|               |111 22 44", 
         "44       |               |       44", 
         "44 22 111|               |111 22 44", 
         "44 22 111|               |111 22 44", 
         "44 22 111 --------------- 111 22 44", 
         "44 22 11  111111111111111  11 22 44", 
         "33 22 1  11111111111111111  1 22 33", 
         "33 22   1111111111111111111   22 33", 
         "33 22                         22 33", 
         "33 2  2222222 2222222 2222222  2 33", 
         "33   22222222 2222222 22222222   33", 
         "3                                 3", 
         "3 3333333333 333333333 3333333333 3", 
         "3 3333333333 333333333 3333333333 3", 
         "3 3333333333 333333333 3333333333 3" 
         }; 

    private Seat[][] seats; 

    public Stadium() { 
    seats = new Seat[ROWS][COLUMNS]; 

    for (int r=0; r< ROWS; r++) { 
        String secString = SEAT_SECTIONS[r]; 
        String rowString = SEAT_ROWS[r]; 
        String numString = SEAT_NUMBERS[r]; 
        for (int c=0; c< COLUMNS; c++) { 
            byte section = (byte)Character.digit(secString.charAt(c),10); // Errors on this line
            char row = (char)rowString.charAt(c); 
            byte number = (byte)Character.digit(numString.charAt(c), 10);// as well as this line 
            if (!Character.isLetter(row)) 
                seats[r][c] = null; 
            else 
                seats[r][c] = new Seat(section, row, number); 
        } 
    }
}
```

When I try to run the test program, I get a String index out of range Exception in the stadium constructor. Specifically on the two lines I marked, where I take the charAt() of the numString and rowString. I've tried putting in other numbers and it seems to work just fine for numbers 1-10 but after that, I get this exception.

Comment: You can debug this so easily. Just check the lengths of each string and compare with the values of `c`.

Comment: What do you suppose that error means, and what don't you understand about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got tab characters instead of spaces in some places. It visually looks like each string is the same width, but some are shorter than others. For example, this:

```
"6                                 4",
```

Is really:

```
"6 \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t   4",
```

Comment: Ah, I see now. Replaced the tabs with spaces and it seems to have done the trick. Thank you so much!